# Computer Vision: SURF (Speeded Up Robust Features) with Color consideration

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, surf, object-recognition

Is it possible to enhance the Speeded Up Robust Features (SURF) Computer Vision algorithm so that it can differentiate equally distributed and shaped objects with different colors?

I am looking for research papers or any other sources that try to enhance SURF so that it can differentiate the same objects with different colors.

Comment: Probably you may tag each keypoint with its color, but SURF is morphological and so doesn't seem to make sense to add "color" as a property. In its usual uses SURF is expected to associate OOIs despite the shading/illumination/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Color-SURF: A surf descriptor with local kernel color histograms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/5353577/5360780/05360809.pdf?arnumber=5360809&authDecision=-203)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than add color to the algorithm it's often easier to convert the image and then run the algorithm on each single color scaler image.

It's worth looking at doing this in another color space rather than RGB - depending on what you are trying to find, doing it in HSV or YUV (at least the UV) parts might make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I guess you don't happen to know of sources that a bit further into this subject in combination with SURF?

Answer (score 1):

I think the addition of color information to the SURF may enhance the performance a little, but not significantly

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.